# How to store into Byte or Byte array

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, byte, tibco

This message is coming from external system and this is coming as bytes,
I have to use it in my Java code. I am taking it as a byte and converting to `String`.

Can anyone help me to accept it as byte only instead of taking it to string and converting to byte.

Here is the output from that external system till equals to:

> wcLDxMXGx8jJ0fHy8/T1AHsSNFw=

I want to store it either in `byte` or `byte[]`.

I have tried doing it myself but it says `error at =`. I have to use it as byte only as taking it as `String` and then converting to `byte` will be problematic and not as expected.

Comment: The external system appears to be sending you Base64 encoded data. Treating that as a raw byte[] will not decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class [**`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) (since Java SE 6 update 3):

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "wcLDxMXGx8jJ0fHy8/T1AHsSNFw=";
    byte[] array = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

**Output**:

```
[-63, -62, -61, -60, -59, -58, -57, -56, -55, -47, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, 0, 123, 18, 52, 92]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream()) {
    try (InputStream externalSource = ...)) {
        for (;;) {
            int b = externalSource.read();
            if (b == -1 || b == 'I') { // End of file or ASCII I
                break;
            }
            bais.write((byte) b);
        }
    }
    byte[] bytes = bais.toByteArray();
}
```

There is a "till" in your question, which I translated into a condition `|| b == 'I'`.
You probably did not intend that. Maybe you used `=` instead of `==`.

The above reads an int which is -1 when end-of-file, a byte value otherwise.

The try-with-resources syntax ensures that `externalSource` and `bais` are closed.